# how to stop old song when new song is playing with Service

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am try to create a music app. I am using this code to stop the song when another song will play but this code does not work . Both songs play together i want to play one by one or if any other song will clicked the stop the previous song and play that song. Any one can help me.

MainActivity:

```
private void clickSong() {
        mListBaiHat.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {    
                String local = mPath.get(i);
                mserviceMusic.setLocalSongRunging(i);   

                try {
                    mserviceMusic.setLocalSong(local);
                    mClickStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause_light);    

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }    

                mHinhAlbum.setImageResource(arrayList.get(i).getHinhAlbum());
                mCLickTenBaiHat.setText(arrayList.get(i).getTenBaiHat());
                mCLickCasy.setText(arrayList.get(i).getTheloai());    

                    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
                    retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    retriever.setDataSource(mPath.get(i));

                    String tenAlbum = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
                    String ten = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

                    mCLickTenBaiHat.setText(ten);
                    mCLickCasy.setText(tenAlbum);

                }

                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("vitri", i);
                bundle.putStringArrayList("tenbai", mPath);


            }
        });
    }
```

Service:

```
public void setLocalSongRunging(int vitri){
    mLocaltionSong = vitri;
}

public void setLocalSong(String localsong) throws IOException {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(localsong);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();            
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=null;

    }else {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to set null mediaPalyer after its release on setOnCompletionListener

Comment: @vishalpatel I try it, but it not work.

Comment: You are creating a new MediaPlayer each time.

Comment: @sunilsunny can you explain it, i don't understand

Comment: you need to set release and null before creating new MediaPlayer instance

Comment: @MCuong check my answer.

Comment: @sunilsunny i try your answer and change but it's not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `MediaPlayer` each time. So your code to stop and release wont work (since different instance of mediaplayer are being used) change your code like this in `setLocalSong(String localsong)`.

```
   public void setLocalSong(String localsong) throws IOException {
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();            
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=null;
    }
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(localsong);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

Comment: it's still like before :(

Comment: it's not play, song name change but no sound @sunulsunny

Comment: @MCuong oops I forgot the code to start the mediaplayer :P. Let me change the code. Try now.